# Resource manager configuration in QJM HA setup of Hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, failover, resourcemanager

We have configured Hadoop as high availability so that we can achieve automatic failover using Quorum Journal Manager. It is working fine as expected.
But we are not sure how to configure resource manager in 2.6.0 version.

Resource manager is needed for running map reduce programs. We need the configuration steps for resource manager failover setup in Hadoop 2.6.0 between the name nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MapReduce. If you have multiple Resource Manager (one Active at a time) you need to set its logical names
http://gethue.com/hadoop-tutorial-yarn-resource-manager-high-availability-ha-in-mr2/

However I am not sure if the logical names for rm1,rm2(...) will be the same. If anybody can confirm this?

It can be achieved in oozie by using "logicaljt" as job-tracker value in your workflow

Source: https://issues.cloudera.org/browse/HUE-1631

Comment: I assume you have already configured properties in yarn-site.xml for multiple RMs
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.5.2/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/ResourceManagerHA.html#Deployment